# extract numbers from repeated block

Tags: linux, bash, sh, uniq

I have a `text` file that contain `repeated` block of nos as given below(with > symbol) and I want to extract repeated values only once.

```
Input

>
1
2
3
4
10
100
>
1
2
3
4
10
100

expected output

1
2
3
4
10
100
```

I tried script

```
#!/bin/sh
uniq -d input > output
```

but it gives output same as input.can anybody suggest a solution on this.Thanks.

Comment: What happens if one line contains the entry `3`, another line the entry `03`, and yet another one the entry `    3` (with spaces). Are they considered equal or different?

Comment: different...if possible make it to 3 to 03

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort it first. Try this

> sort input | uniq -d

or if you want to save it as a file

> sort input | uniq -d > output

Comment: Note that this can be simplified to `sort -i input`.

Comment: Ah, my typo: Wanted do say: `sort -u input`. No need to pipe into _uniq_.

Comment: @user1934428 ah yes, i didnt think of that. great answer

Comment: looking at it now, i think the OP wants the `>` to be removed as well. so to add on to your answer, we could do  `sort -u input | sed 1d`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try:

```
 sort -n -u input > output
```